# tomcat looks like it is reloading constantly

Tags: tomcat

I'm not a tomcat expert by any means, but this just looks wrong to me...

```
Jan 24, 2014 10:05:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 24, 2014 10:05:34 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
```

I get this same block of logging in the catalina.out file every 15 minutes, and this has been going on for >2 years on this application. Doesn't the mean that tomcat is reloading every 15 minutes?

Comment: Those aren't normal, but they're also probably two separate and distinct issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is normal. The second one means you already have another process bound to port 8080. Do you by any chance have two instances of Tomcat running? Are you perhaps trying to start a second instance every 15 minutes? ... which will of course fail.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be puppet. The version of tomcat we are running does not handle 'service tomcat status' properly, so every puppet run failed the status check for tomcat, launching 'service tomcat start' which fails and generates the log entry above. However, I believe this is causing several other problems with our service, so I wrote a status function within the tomcat startup script myself:

```
status() {
    proc=`ps aux | grep tomcat | grep catalina | awk '{print $2}'`
    numproc=`echo $proc | wc -w`
    if [ $numproc -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "tomcat (pid $proc) is running..."
    else
        echo "tomcat is stopped..."
    fi
}
```